# How to store custom class object into spaCy.doc and use `doc.to_disk`?

Tags: python, spacy

I want to store my class object into `spacy.Doc` and save it with `doc.to_disk`, as follows:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.vocab import Vocab
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int


doc = Doc(Vocab(), [])
doc.user_data["foo"] = Foo(1)
doc.to_disk("/tmp/fooo")
```

But this code raise Errors:

```
TypeError: can not serialize 'Foo' object
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Per this thread [here](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/82), you should try the following work around:

```py
    def remove_unserializable_results(doc):
        doc.user_data = {}
        for x in dir(doc._):
            if x in ['get', 'set', 'has']: continue
            setattr(doc._, x, None)
        for token in doc:
            for x in dir(token._):
                if x in ['get', 'set', 'has']: continue
                setattr(token._, x, None)
        return doc

nlp.add_pipe(remove_unserializable_results, last=True)
```